# iphone -- XCode 4 jumps to main at simulator stop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

when I press stop on the simulator in XCode 4, XCode jumps to the main.m file.  Anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Behaviors.  Choose "Run Completes" in the left hand side.  Check the box next to "Show Tab" and enter a tab name. I use "Edit".

This way whenever you stop, you will always be back at a tab called Edit.

Comment: ok that is close to what I wanted.  I wanted it to stay the same as before when the run completes.  I just had to go to the same preference menu and click Show -> navigator -> Project Navigator, and Show -> editor as -> Current Editor.